# vb.net Regex remove a tags with mailto

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a text for example:

```
" Visit <a href="http://www.flexstaff.com">www.flexstaff.com</a> for details
 Email <a href="mailto:rachel@flexstaff.com">rachel@flexstaff.com</a> apply online."
```

I would like to delete **only** the a tags that contain "**mailto**" so

```
<a href="mailto:rachel@flexstaff.com">rachel@flexstaff.com</a> will become
rachel@flexstaff.com
```

I have this regex:

```
  Dim rgxMailTo = New Regex("<a\b\s[^<>]*(?<=@.*)>|(?<=@.*)</a>",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
  Dim ret As String = rgxMailTo.Replace(text, Environment.NewLine)
```

But it selects other a tags as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the match with `$1`.

```
<a\b\s*[^<>]*\bmailto\b[^<>]*>([^<>]*)<\/a>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eX8bR6/4)

To select only the tags.

```
<a\b\s*[^<>]*\bmailto\b[^<>]*>|(?<=<a\b\s*[^<>]*\bmailto\b[^<>]*>[^<>]*)<\/a>
```

Comment: or `<a\b\s*[^<>]*\bmailto\b[^<>]*@[^<>]*>([^<>]*)<\/a>`

Comment: No, i don't want it to capture the email address within the tag, only the a tag arounds it.
It should select only:
    <a href="mailto:rachel@flexstaff.com"></a>

Comment: you the one asked like `<a href="mailto:rachel@flexstaff.com">rachel@flexstaff.com</a> will become
rachel@flexstaff.com`

Comment: It works in your Demo because you replace the tags with the E-mail address.
i need it to delete without replacements.

Comment: to delete the tags, you must need to use the replace function i think.

Comment: That's true, after i will select the tags i will replace them with " ".
i just need to find a way to select the tags without the Email inside of them.

Comment: Thank you Raj, i will post another question in 1 hour :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456449/vb-net-regex-select-a-tags-without-its-data-extracted 
please answer me there

Answer (score 0):

If your text is of uncertain source (so it was not all generated in 100% predictable way), using regex is a very bad idea - trust me, I've been there.

One option is to use [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), and load the HTML as an XElement (C#, as I have sample on hand):

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(HTML);
htmlDoc.OptionOutputAsXml = true;

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                htmlDoc.Save(stream);
                stream.Position = 0;

                var xelement = XElement.Load(stream);
                DoStuffToXElement(xelement);
            }
```

Note, that in case you have just a fragment without a root element:

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
<img src="#"/>
```

Remember to wrap it in something neutral, like `htmlDoc.LoadHtml("<div>"+HTML+"</div>");`

Now you can use LinqToXml to find whatever you need, traverse the tree or do anything quite safely:

```
xHtml
  .Descendants()
    .Where(e=>e.Name.LocalName.Equals("a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
    && e.Attribute("href") != null 
    && e.Attribute("href").Value.StartsWith("mailto:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  .Remove();
```

Final note: this is nearly always much slower than regex - if time is important (for example you do it at every page load or sth) it might be too slow, but I guess this kind of processing can be done beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power of LINQ to XML like this:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.XPath

Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim str As String = "Visit <a href=""http://www.flexstaff.com"">www.flexstaff.com</a> for details\nEmail <a href=""mailto:rachel@flexstaff.com"">rachel@flexstaff.com</a> apply online."
    Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version= '1.0'?><root>" + str + "</root>")
    Dim query = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//a[contains(@href,'mailto')]")

    For Each element In query
        element.Remove()
    Next element
    Dim Res As String = xDoc.ToString().Replace("<root>", String.Empty).Replace("</root>", String.Empty)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Outoput (`Res`):

```
Visit <a href="http://www.flexstaff.com">www.flexstaff.com</a> for details\nEmail  apply online.
```