# vb.net Regex - Replace a tags without replacing span tags

Tags: regex, vb.net

My function needs to replace a tags from a string if the data extracted in it has a url.
for example:

```
<a href=www.cnn.com>www.cnn.com</a>
```

will be replace with:

```
 www.cnn.com
```

That works fine but when i have a string like:

```
<a href=www.cnn.com><span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">www.cnn.com</span></a>
```

I get only:

```
www.cnn.com
```

when i actually want to stay with:

```
<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">www.cnn.com</span>
```

What do i need to add to the code for it to work?

This is my function:

```
Dim ret As String = text

'If it looks like a URL
Dim regURL As New Regex("(www|\.org\b|\.com\b|http)")
'Gets a Tags regex
Dim rxgATags = New Regex("<[^>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) 

'Gets all matches of <a></a> and adds them to a list
Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(ret, "<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)</a>") 

'for each <a></a> in the text check it's content, if it looks like URL then delete the <a></a>
For Each m In matches
'tmpText holds the data extracted within the a tags. /visit at.../www.applyhere.com
        Dim tmpText = rxgATags.Replace(m.ToString, "")

        If regURL.IsMatch(tmpText) Then
            ret = ret.Replace(m.ToString, tmpText)
        End If
Next

Return ret
```

Comment: use this `@"</?a\b[^>]*>"` regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add this to my code:

```
'Selects only the A tags without the data extracted between them
Dim rxgATagsOnly = New Regex("</?a\b[^>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    For Each m In matches
        'tmpText holds the data extracted within the a tags. /visit at.../www.applyhere.com
        Dim tmpText = rxgATagsContent.Replace(m.ToString, "")

        'if the data extract between the tags looks like a URL then take off the a tags without touching the span tags.
        If regURL.IsMatch(tmpText) Then
            'select everything but a tags
            Dim noATagsStr As String = rxgATagsOnly.Replace(m.ToString, Environment.NewLine)
            'replaces string with a tag to non a tag string keeping it's span tags
            ret = ret.Replace(m.ToString, noATagsStr)

        End If
    Next
```

so from the string:

```
<a href=www.cnn.com><span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">www.cnn.com</span></a>
```

i selected only the a tags with  Avinash Raj regex 
and then replaced them with "".
Thank you all for answering.

Answer (score 0):

The following Regex will remove all HTML tags:

```
string someString = "<a href=www.one.co.il><span style=\"color: rgb(255, 0, 255);\">www.visitus.com</span></a>";

string target = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(someString, @"<[^>]*>", "", RegexOptions.Compiled).ToString();
```

This is the Regex you want : `<[^>]*>`

Result of my code : `www.visitus.com`

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex - `<a\s*[^<>]*>|</a>` - that will match all `<a>` nodes, both opening and close ones.

You do not need to use `regURL`, this can be built into the `rxATags` regex. We can make sure it is an URL-referencing `<a>` tag by checking `href` and `regURL alternatives, then grab everything in between the opening and close`` tags, and then use only what is in between.

```
Dim ret As String = "<a href=www.one.co.il><span style=""color: rgb(255, 0, 255);"">www.visitus.com</span></a>"
'Gets a Tags regex
Dim rxgATags = New Regex("(<a\s*[^<>]*href=[""']?(?:www|\.org\b|\.com\b|http)[^<>]*>)((?>\s*<(?<t>[\w.-]+)[^<>]*?>[^<>]*?</\k<t>>\s*)+)(</a>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim replacement As String = "$2"
ret = rxgATags.Replace(ret, replacement)
```

[image]